# dummy data with float variables

Tags: numpy, range

I try to create some dummy location data with the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import time

def location():

    start_time = time.time()

    latitude = choice([-1, 1]) * round(np.float32(choice(range(0, 90000000, 1))) / 1000000, 6)
    longitude = choice([-1, 1]) * round(np.float32(choice(range(0, 180000000, 1))) / 1000000, 6)
    lapse = time.time() - start_time
    return latitude, longitude, lapse
```

But lapse is around 5.4 seconds.. Is there a way to make it faster ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically picking a random integer from that range array and assuming a uniform distribution of that elements in that range array for the picking. We could do the same task with [`numpy.random.random_integers`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_integers.html#numpy.random.random_integers) that follows `“discrete uniform” distribution`. This function lets us specify the `low` and `high` values. The `high` value is inclusive here. So, to simulate our case, we need to subtract `1`.

Thus, an alternative way would be like so -

```
get_num = np.random.random_integers
lat = np.random.choice([-1, 1])*round(get_num(0,90000000-1)/1000000.0,6)
lon = np.random.choice([-1, 1])*round(get_num(0,180000000-1)/1000000.0,6)
```

Timings -

```
In [5]: %timeit np.random.choice([-1, 1])*round(get_num(0,90000000-1)/1000000.0,6)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit np.random.choice([-1, 1])*round(get_num(0,180000000-1)/1000000.0,6)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: Reading the doc, they say it is deprecated. So I use randint instead of get_num, which is in the random module - 11.4 ns. Thank you for the hint ! ;)